# tcolorbox environment inside longtable — it is possible?

Tags: longtable, tcolorbox

I try to use `tcolorbox` environment inside `longtable` environments.
Minimal sample:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\begin{longtable}{|p{\linewidth}|}
\hline
\begin{tcolorbox}
\lipsum[3]
\end{tcolorbox}
\\
\hline
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

Unfortunately, the code does not compile:

```
! Misplaced \noalign.                                                                                                            
\pagebreak ->\noalign                                                                                                            
                      {\ifnum `}=0\fi \@testopt {\LT@no@pgbk -}4                                                                 
l.11 \end{tcolorbox}
```

Is there any magic option/hack/workaround to do it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You must reset the `before` key. In the default it contains a \pagebreak and as longtable redefines \pagebreak you get errors. This here compiles:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\begin{longtable}{|p{\linewidth}|}
\hline
\begin{tcolorbox}[before={}]
\lipsum[3]
\end{tcolorbox}
\\
\hline
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

Some non-default options of the `tcolorbox` environment also appear to cause this issue. Specifically, I have experienced that similar error messages pop up when trying to place a `tcolorbox` environment in a `longtable` if it uses any of the following options:

- `breakable`
- `lines before break=X`
- and possibly other pagebreak-related settings

These settings do not appear in the minimum example provided by the OP, but other users may happen to be dealing with environments where they're using such settings and end up here (that's exactly how I ended up here).

[Ulrike's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/351232/121370) should also be applied!